# Is there better way to store column data into Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am storing my column data into Python list, Name of the list should be the same as the column name.

I am using this code:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql

db = mysql.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "",
    database = "DB"
)
cursor = db.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM sample1"
cursor.execute(query)
records = cursor.fetchall()

########  LIST ALL THE COLUMNS ######### 
field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]

#Creating list with column name
for col in field_names:
    exec(col + "=[]")

#appending records into list
for record in records:
    first_name.append(record[0])
    last_name.append(record[1])
    full_name.append(record[2])
```

If I need to add a new column in future, Again I have to add "abc.append(record[3])".

Is there any way to create the list and append data into it on the fly?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables).  A common solution is to use a dictionary to store the data using the *name* for the key.

Comment: Is there a way to do it by using list??

Comment: The values of the dictionary can be lists - use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for the dictionary.

Comment: Let me try. Thanks